# What does "prometheus_target_scrape_pool_sync_total" means?

Tags: prometheus

I found some prometheus metrics whose help comments didn't make me fully understand.

```
# HELP prometheus_target_scrape_pool_sync_total Total number of syncs that were executed on a scrape pool.
```

Above metrics were associated with prometheus target. What does `prometheus_target_scrape_pool_sync_total` means?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from [the source code](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/66da1d51fd92977df9a9bf4f8c69303b2ba8d88e/scrape/scrape.go#L484-L515), it counts how many times that `Sync()` function was called (I don't see this counter anywhere else). The `Sync()` function has this annotation:

> Sync converts target groups into actual scrape targets and synchronizes the currently running scraper with the resulting set and returns all scraped and dropped targets.

It doesn't make much sense to me, but judging from what it counts, I guess it is one of those metrics the devs made for themselves, to debug scraping or service discovery.